# animation not working in xcode 8 playground swift 3

Tags: animation, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to simply learn more about animations in Xcode 8 playground using swift 3. I have already learned that swift no longer uses XCPlayground, instead, using "import PlaygroundSupport".

I can not get anything to show in the Assistant Editor. Does anyone know the fix for this or is it just a bug with the new Xcode 8

Any help would be awesome. Thanks.

```
import UIKit

import PlaygroundSupport

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 375.0, height: 667.0))
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView =  containerView

let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0))
circle.center = containerView.center
circle.layer.cornerRadius = 25.0

let startingColor = UIColor(red: (253.0/255.0), green: (159.0/255.0), blue: (47.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
circle.backgroundColor = startingColor

containerView.addSubview(circle);

let rectangle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0))
rectangle.center = containerView.center
rectangle.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0

rectangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

containerView.addSubview(rectangle)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
    let endingColor = UIColor(red: (255.0/255.0), green: (61.0/255.0), blue: (24.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
    circle.backgroundColor = endingColor

    let scaleTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 5.0, y: 5.0)

    circle.transform = scaleTransform

    let rotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 3.14)

    rectangle.transform = rotationTransform
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the assistant editor to view the live view of the animation as mentioned in the [article](https://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/prototyping-uiview-animations-swift-playground/) you're basing this off