# How to use downloadable swift playgrounds?

Tags: swift, xcode8

I am new to swift.

I recently [downloaded](https://github.com/uraimo/Awesome-Swift-Playgrounds) some examples of swift playgrounds by apple such as Newtonscradle and Balloons, but I am unable to view them using the assistant editor of X code(I have version 8.2.1). I was wondering how I can solve this problem.

Initially, I searched for how I can download Scenekit, Cocoa, and XCPlayground because I thought my mac does not have them. However, I couldn't find out how to download them, and I am uncertain about whether this is the real problem.

I also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577359/animation-not-working-in-xcode-8-playground-swift-3) which was on stackoverflow, and tried out the code. However, this didn't work out either. When I put it in, it only says "Running (document name)" and stays like that forever.

Does anyone know how I can view these codes on the assistant editor? Also, I am currently learning swift through the iBook, "The Swift Programming Language Swift 3.1 edition," but are there any other ways to learn swift with an Mac computer? I want to finish making something in two weeks for the WWDC17.

Regards,
RK2

Answer (score 0):

If you clone the project you linked to, and then update the submodules (the playgrounds appear to be linked to as submodules from other GitHub projects) you should have one or more .playground files under each subfolder under the playgrounds folder. Simply open the playground file  you want in Xcode by double-clicking it in Finder.